# How to get Div Row ID in Code Behind?

Tags: asp.net, c

I would like to ask how do I get this control at code behind. I know it can be done at client side. I tried but get an error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

What is the correct method to get it? If it is textbox, I just declare textbox. But this is div class.

Code Behind

```
 TableRow trStatusB = fvAddOn.FindControl("EditProductNameRow") as TableRow;
```

Client Side

```
 <div class="Row" id="EditNameRow" runat="server"> 
</div>
```

Comment: What is `fvAddOn`? If these controls aren't maked with `runat=server` you can't access them at serverside because they are not initialized in server memory. A page will only build up the control hierarchy of all controls that are server-controls.

Comment: Thx. It work. I tried to find around but did not manage to find it. the fv means formview control.